# test thunk created with createAsyncThunk

Tags: jestjs, redux-toolkit

I know this has been asked before, but i'm wondering if now with a new updated version of `redux-toolkit` ("@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.1") this could have changed.

**action**

```js
const myThunk = createAsyncThunk('foobar', myService);
```

**test**

```js
import createStore from './store';
const store = createStore(somePreloadedState);

await store.dispatch(myThunk(someArgs));
expect(myService).toBeCalledWith(someArgs); // this worked fine
```

**issue**

Now the test is failing due to a second argument being present in the service call:

```
someArgs, {"dispatch": [Function dispatch], "extra": undefined, "fulfillWithValue":...
```

I can fix this either by expect any second argument:

`expect(myService).toBeCalledWith(someArgs, expect.anything());`

Or by creating the thunk in a different way:

`const myThunk = createAsyncThunk('foobar', args => myService(args));`

But I would rather not have to change all this if I don't have to, so **is this something that was added new?** or **should I mock createAsyncThunk in any way?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note I know this test is pretty much useless in the example, but it is an excerpt

Comment: `expect(myService).toBeCalledWith(someArgs, expect.anything());` works

Answer (score 1):

`createAsyncThunk` has been passing in this second argument for as long as it exists, so nothing has changed here, apart from that second argument getting a few extra properties in 1.6.0.

Both of your ways around that are valid ways around your problem, but of course you will have some code changes.

Generally, you should not mock `createAsyncThunk` and testing it this way is probably also not a lot of value.

Instead, we recommend mocking your actual api using something like `msw` and doing an integration test, treating Redux as an implementation detail and not testing it separately.

See https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-tests for more background.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I know in my example the test doesn't seem to have a value, but if I have an action creator that dispatches several other actions it's something I want to test. So i'll go ahead with the `expect.anything` or similar.

Comment: Generally, you should probably not dispatch too many other actions, but have multiple other reducers just listen for the same actions. Multiple actions dispatched in sequence can cause multiple rerenders on React side instead of just one rerender for multiple reducers reacting to one action. https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#allow-many-reducers-to-respond-to-the-same-action